# Multiple inheritance vs usage of Activity & ListActivity Class in Java

Tags: android, android-listview

I have just started working with Android `ListView`. However, `setAdapter` function in my program works only when `ListActivity` is extended by class `DisplayMovie`. While I use `ListActivity` and remove `Activity`, the application crashes. Since multiple Inheritance cannot be supported, I wish to know if there is a way by which I can use both `ListViewActivity` as well as `Activity` classes in my program.

```
//public class DisplayMovies extends ListActivity {
public class DisplayMovies extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public String flixURL="";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main3);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();        
        int myzip = extras.getInt("globalZip");        
        flixURL=("http://servermin.com:19818/cgi-bin/movielog.pl?zip=" + myzip);        
        displayAllMovieList();                
    }

    public void displayAllMovieList()
    {
        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
        URL url;

        try 
        {
            url = new URL(flixURL);
            Document doc = null;
            doc=builder.build(url);             
            Element root = doc.getRootElement();                                
            List children = root.getChild("movies").getChildren("movie");

            System.out.println("Tracker3");
                    int MovieNum=children.size();  //Count the number of Movies                 
                    String[] MovieName=new String[MovieNum]; //Initialize a String 
                    String[] MovieCover=new String[MovieNum];                                       
                    String[] ShowTime=new String[MovieNum];                 
                    String TheatereName = ((Element) doc.getRootElement().getChild("movies").getChildren("movie").get(0)).getAttributeValue( "theatre" );                                       
                    String TweetText="";                                          
                    for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) 
                    {   
                        Element movieAtt = (Element)doc.getRootElement().getChild("movies").getChildren("movie").get(i);                                            
                        MovieName[i]=movieAtt.getAttributeValue( "Title" );
                        MovieCover[i]=movieAtt.getAttributeValue( "cover" );
                        ShowTime[i]=movieAtt.getAttributeValue( "showtime" );
                            finalTime=movieAtt.getAttributeValue( "showtime" ).substring(0,8);
                        TweetText+=" I will see "+movieAtt.getAttributeValue("Title")+" at "+TheatereName+" at "+finalTime+"\n";


                        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MovieName);
                        setListAdapter(adapter);

                        //TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                        //tv.setText(TweetText);
                        //setContentView(tv);                                               
                    }                     

        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e1) 
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("ErrorThrowedIs: "+e1);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e1.toString(),5);
        } 
        catch (JDOMException e2) 
        {
            e2.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("ErrorThrowedIs: "+e2);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e2.toString(),5);
        }
        catch (IOException e3) 
        {
            e3.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("ErrorThrowedIs: "+e3);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e3.toString(),5);
        }
    }
}
```

Error Log Says :

```
11-21 02:18:19.609: W/dalvikvm(21193): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7d0)
11-21 02:18:19.629: E/AndroidRuntime(21193): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-21 02:18:19.629: E/AndroidRuntime(21193): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vj/com.vj.DisplayMovies}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
11-21 02:18:19.629: E/AndroidRuntime(21193):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
11-21 02:18:19.629: E/AndroidRuntime(21193):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-21 02:18:19.629: E/AndroidRuntime(21193):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-21 02:18:19.629: E/AndroidRuntime(21193):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-21 02:18:19.629: E/AndroidRuntime(21193):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-21 02:18:19.629: E/AndroidRuntime(21193):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-21 02:18:19.629: E/AndroidRuntime(21193):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-21 02:18:19.629: E/AndroidRuntime(21193):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-21 02:18:19.629: E/AndroidRuntime(21193):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-21 02:18:19.629: E/AndroidRuntime(21193):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
11-21 02:18:19.629: E/AndroidRuntime(21193):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-21 02:18:19.629: E/AndroidRuntime(21193):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-21 02:18:19.629: E/AndroidRuntime(21193): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
11-21 02:18:19.629: E/AndroidRuntime(21193):    at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:245)
11-21 02:18:19.629: E/AndroidRuntime(21193):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:203)
11-21 02:18:19.629: E/AndroidRuntime(21193):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
11-21 02:18:19.629: E/AndroidRuntime(21193):    at com.vj.DisplayMovies.onCreate(DisplayMovies.java:30)
11-21 02:18:19.629: E/AndroidRuntime(21193):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-21 02:18:19.629: E/AndroidRuntime(21193):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-21 02:18:19.629: E/AndroidRuntime(21193):    ... 11 more
```

Updated XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#00FF00"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

     <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#FF0000"
               android:text="No data"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Updated Code for the class:

```
public class DisplayMovies extends ListActivity {
//public class DisplayMovies extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public String flixURL="";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main3);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();        
        int myzip = extras.getInt("globalZip");        
        flixURL=("http://myweb.com/cgi-bin/movielog.pl?zip=" + myzip);      
        displayAllMovieList();                
    }

    public void displayAllMovieList()
    {
        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
        URL url;

        try 
        {
            url = new URL(flixURL);
            Document doc = null;
            doc=builder.build(url);             
            Element root = doc.getRootElement();                                
            List children = root.getChild("movies").getChildren("movie");

            System.out.println("Tracker2");
                    System.out.println("Tracker3");
                    int MovieNum=children.size();  //Count the number of Movies                 
                    String[] MovieName=new String[MovieNum]; //Initialize a String 
                    String[] MovieCover=new String[MovieNum];                                       
                    String[] ShowTime=new String[MovieNum];                 
                    String TheatereName = ((Element) doc.getRootElement().getChild("movies").getChildren("movie").get(0)).getAttributeValue( "theatre" );                                       
                    String TweetText="";                                          
                    for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) 
                    {   
                        Element movieAtt = (Element)doc.getRootElement().getChild("movies").getChildren("movie").get(i);                                            
                        MovieName[i]=movieAtt.getAttributeValue( "Title" );
                        MovieCover[i]=movieAtt.getAttributeValue( "cover" );
                        ShowTime[i]=movieAtt.getAttributeValue( "showtime" );
                            finalTime=movieAtt.getAttributeValue( "showtime" ).substring(0,8);  TweetText+=" I will see "+movieAtt.getAttributeValue("Title")+" at "+TheatereName+" at "+finalTime+"\n";


                        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MovieName);
                        setListAdapter(adapter);


                }               
        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e1) 
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("ErrorThrowedIs: "+e1);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e1.toString(),5);
        } 
        catch (JDOMException e2) 
        {
            e2.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("ErrorThrowedIs: "+e2);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e2.toString(),5);
        }
        catch (IOException e3) 
        {
            e3.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("ErrorThrowedIs: "+e3);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e3.toString(),5);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exact crash error do you receive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if your app crashes, and you're asking a question, make sure you also include the stacktrace from the log.

Regarding your question, make sure you understand the preconditions to using `ListActivity`: you MUST have a listview in your layout, with an `android:id="@android:id/list"` (as stated in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)). I'm quite positive this is the reason your app crashes.

You don't need multiple inheritance here anyway: `ListActivity` extends `Activity`, it would make no sense to extend them both, even if Java had multiple inheritance.

Comment: Yes, i believed that ListActivity extends Activity.. I am adding the trace.. and yes i believe i did not added Listview in my XML

Comment: btw, if you only need a listview in your layout, you can omit `setContentView`: the `ListActivity` will supply a default layout (it's also described in the docs).

Comment: i was trying hands out on this. Actually i want to implement a list view with 3 items, one text, one image and on radio button. Could you please let me know how can we perform that. 

I have 
String[] MovieName=new String[MovieNum]; //Has Movie Name Text
String[] MovieCover=new String[MovieNum]; // Has Movie Iamge URL

Can you help me with this with a probable sample code ?

Comment: this is a separate issue - create a question for that. btw, your log shows that my suggestion about the list was right

Comment: Ok. I wil do that...BTW it is crashing again..I have included the Linear layout in the corresponding xml file for the class mentioned above. And it is still throwing the same error.

Comment: are you sure you understood my answer correctly? ListActivity will crash if you don't have a listview with the aforementioned id in your layout - and you only have two textviews there, no listview (you can see an example of listview declaration in the link I provided)

Comment: Oops !! I pasted the wrong one.. Please see again.. i an using this code  in the xml :

Comment: I have updated it. it is like... 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android=""
     android:layout_width=""
     android:layout_height=""
     android:orientation="">

<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

     <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:text="No data"/>
</LinearLayout>

Comment: I rewrote XML now. I was referring to wrong XML. Created another one and referred from that.